# Input field name syntax

Tags: php, html

I have got code from a website as:

```
<input type="text" class="username" name="f[username]" />
```

While when I want to get form value in php as

```
echo $_POST["f[username]"];
```

It shows nothing

Comment: check `print_r($_POST);` and you will come to know how to get value

Comment: Try `echo $_POST["f['username']"];`

Comment: This is NOT how nested arrays work. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While when I want to get form value in php as
>
> ```
> echo $_POST["f[username]"];
> ```

Well [that's not how you get it](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays).

```
echo $_POST["f"]["username"];
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP special cases `[]` characters in field names in data which populates $_POST and $_GET. It uses them to generate arrays.

```
$_POST['f']['username']
```

Answer (score 0):

Well another answer from planet, don't make yourself hard to solve something, just change the name with familiar

```
<input type="text" class="username" name="username" />
```

then echo it in your php

```
echo $_POST['username'];
```